# Eclipse 4.2 crashes on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to run Eclipse 4.2 on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit PC with a oneiric kernel.

I have both 32bit and 64bit versions, but neither work.

I've installed jdk6.

When I run the 32bit, this error message pops up:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0.v201206081400/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/goister/android/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 408015
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

In my terminal, I get the following output

```
/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgiogconf.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgiogconf.so
/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
```

When I run the 64bit, this error message pops up:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0.v201206081400/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/goister/android/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 418015
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/goister/android/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

In my terminal, I get the following output

```
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: gosh
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: gosh
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:466)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:395)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Activator.run(Activator.java:75)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgiogconf.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgiogconf.so
/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your JVM and Eclipse same architecture?

Comment: I can't remember if my JDK is 32bit or 64bit. How do I check?

Comment: check release file in your JDK dir.

Comment: Not sure where that is. I did an apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Comment: Not sure, but i think you can find in /usr/lib/jvm/

Comment: Never mind, figured out what was wrong. I had a corrupted 64bit version of eclipse.